# Method supportInvalidateOptionsMenu throws stackoverflowerror at android 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread, stack-overflow

I use actionbarsherlock in my project, and I'm trying to manipulate the action bar from within the fragments...

So in my first fragment shown, I override onPrepareOptionsMenu to invalidate the actionbar and change title... but when I try calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(), I get a java.lang.StackOverflowError (It doesn't happens on android 4.3 though)...

I've tried [Delyan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898940/sherlock-actionbar-invalidateoptionsmenu) without success... My code and Log follows below, any suggestions? Thanks in advance

---------Code---------

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    Log.e("CategoriasLista", "Executou onPrepareOptionsMenu");
    int currentTab = ((MainActivity)getSherlockActivity()).getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    if(currentTab==0){
        ActionBar bar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        //getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        ((MainActivity)getSherlockActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                ((MainActivity)getSherlockActivity()).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
        bar.setNavigationMode(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        bar.setTitle("Categorias");

    }
}
```

---------Log-----------

```
10-21 09:35:32.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.getClassLoaderImpl(Class.java:431)
    at java.lang.Class.getClassLoader(Class.java:398)
    at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:68)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:251)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista$1.run(CategoriasLista.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista.onPrepareOptionsMenu(CategoriasLista.java:57)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onPreparePanel(Watson.java:98)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackPrepareOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:581)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:494)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista$1.run(CategoriasLista.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista.onPrepareOptionsMenu(CategoriasLista.java:57)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onPreparePanel(Watson.java:98)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackPrepareOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:581)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:494)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista$1.run(CategoriasLista.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista.onPrepareOptionsMenu(CategoriasLista.java:57)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onPreparePanel(Watson.java:98)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackPrepareOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:581)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:494)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista$1.run(CategoriasLista.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista.onPrepareOptionsMenu(CategoriasLista.java:57)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onPreparePanel(Watson.java:98)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackPrepareOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:581)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:494)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
    at br.com.maisapp.Categorias.CategoriasLista$1.run(CategoriasLista.java:60)
    at android.app.Ac
```

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely throwing an Exception because you're trying to invalidate it in the wrong place.

If you simply want to change the title, then move the logic to your onActivityCreated method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  getSherlockActivity.setTitle("Categorias");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this doesn't works for me because I'm inside a fragment? After pasting your code to my fragment, needed to pass `Bundle savedInstanceState` as a parameter to `onActivityCreated`... After this, I'm still unable to invalidate the menu, althoug I'm not getting any erros this time

Comment: I need to invalidade the menu, as there is a spinner from another tab that is appearing when my app starts (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451385/ive-changed-tabs-order-and-now-cant-set-actionbar-sherlock-properly)

Comment: Try calling getSupportActionBar() before invalidating with getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: Thanks for answering, but even calling getSupportActionBar() before, I still get StackOverflowError